# eMule not connected

Tags: router, tcp, emule

I'm using eMule v0.50a on Windows 7.
After installation, I clicked 'connect'
It is not connected.

Please see the attached screenshot.
It reads 'eD2K:Connecting, Kad:Connecting | Preparing'

How can I make that 'preparing' to 'prepared' or 'okay'?

In Option > Connection, I tested ports.
The result is as follows.

Testing IP: c-69-140-18-191.hsd1.md.comcast.net (69.140.18.191)

Starting TCP connection test...
TCP test failed! UDP test will not be performed.

Connection test finished. 
Results in detail:

TCP connection test failed.
It was not possible, to establish a TCP connection to your eMule.
Other users will only be able to connect to you with the help of a server, resulting in a low ID for you. While eMule still works, this will give you several disadvantages. Therfore it is highly recommended to solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: Please indicate the environment you are attempting to run this.  Is this a home network?  company network?  univerity network?  In any event, have you considered the possibility that your provider is not allowing this type of activity?

Comment: It's home network and I'm using Comcast internet. I'm not sure if the provider is not allowing eMule.

Comment: I'd check their website and/or contacting them directly.

Comment: mdpc/  contacting who?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

- Choose any random port number ( > 1024 and UN-reserved ) e.g. 29123 and then go to your router's home page ( that is the same as your IP address's Gateway ). To find this information run the following in a command prompt`ipconfig /all` ( assume you are running an NT based OS ) and find your netwwork adapter's gateway address.
- type the gateway address in your  browser's address URL e.g. `192.168.1.1`
- Now you need to ensure that your PC ALWAYS has the same LAN IP everytime its connected. 
  Most routers will let you do it in the LAN options section. Consult your router's  documentation for this
- Usually the advanced option in your router has port forwarding. Take your PC's IP Address and denote that IP address as RESERVED .
- Now you are ready to port forward. This is USUALLY In the advanced section of the router, where it may have other options like DDNS QOS etc. In the port forwarding section for both UDP and TCP add the source and destination as the IP address of your PC for that specific Port # e.g. 29123
- Save settings and reboot router.
- Now go to Emule and uncheck option for UPNP forwarding and add that port number as your static port.
- Do a port test.You should be good like 95% times.For the rest your ISP may 'smell'  the usage for that specific IP port and may block it and you would need to change it every now and often 
  HTH 
  Sam

Answer (score 0):

To get a high-ID and pass those tests you need to open/forward the ports in your firewall/router to allow them in.  Look in the connection options to figure out which ports your eMule is trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 for KAD to work I had to setup for UDP port forwarding on my router, and also add to windows firewall a new rule with the UDP port number, and specifying also that the user of that rule is Emule.exe.